# Iterate with 2 Indexes Variable in Python

Tags: python

Is there a better or cleaner way to achieve the results below?  I have 4 conditions and half of the code is filled with "while-loop", i += 1, and j += 1.

```
i = 0
j = 0
limit1 = 2
limit2 = 4

while (i < limit1 and j < limit2):
    lists.append ('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, j))
    j += 1
    lists.append ('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, j))
    i += 1
    j += 1

for i in lists:
    print (i)
```

**Results:**

```
First index: 0  Second index: 0
First index: 0  Second index: 1
First index: 1  Second index: 2
First index: 1  Second index: 3
```

Comment: The name `lists` says that that variable consists of multiple lists, but it doesn't. It's just a list of ints. It'd probably be a good idea to use a different name.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, it's a list of strings that could possibly be described as "lists".

Comment: Whoops, list of strings, not list of ints. In any case, calling strings lists is a bad idea; they're not lists, and they behave very differently from lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite straightforward to just compute `j` from `i`:

```
for i in xrange(limit1):
    l.append('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, 2*i))
    l.append('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, 2*i+1))
```

This assumes `limit2` is twice `limit1`. If that isn't always the case, you can add an additional check:

```
for i in xrange(limit1):
    if 2*i >= limit2:
        break
    l.append('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, 2*i))
    l.append('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, 2*i+1))
```

or compute which limit to use up front:

```
for i in xrange(min(limit1, (limit2 + 1)//2)):
```

though as you can see, the limit computation may be error-prone.

Note that if `limit2` isn't a multiple of 2, your code may emit an entry for `j == limit2`:

```
>>> lists = []
>>> i = 0
>>> j = 0
>>> limit1 = 2
>>> limit2 = 3
>>> while (i < limit1 and j < limit2):
...     lists.append ('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, j))
...     j += 1
...     lists.append ('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (i, j))
...     i += 1
...     j += 1
...
>>> for i in lists:
...     print (i)
...
First index: 0, Second index: 0
First index: 0, Second index: 1
First index: 1, Second index: 2
First index: 1, Second index: 3
```

If this isn't desired, we can rearrange the loop to go by `j` instead of `i`:

```
for j in xrange(min(limit2, limit1*2)):
    l.append('First index: %d, Second index: %d' % (j//2, j))
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily break when j is greater than limit2.

Comment: @DTing: Indeed. It assumes that `limit2 == 2*limit1`. I can make that assumption explicit and add a version where that assumption isn't made.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you for the detail break down.  Time to review those Summation class materials.

Answer (score 1):

```
lists = ['First index: %d, Second index %d' % (j//2, j) for j in range(limit2) if j//2 < limit1]
```

Comment: This does something completely different from what's desired.

Comment: You're right. I guess I'm not sure why what's desired is desired, but I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Better. It's important to note that if `limit2` isn't a multiple of 2, this code won't emit an entry for `j == limit2`, while the question's code often will. Whether this is a bug in the original code is something only the questioner can tell us.